# spark ClassCastException:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_

Tags: apache-spark

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

I get the error above when I use `dataset.map()`. Why?

Comment: have the same problem here, do you got any solution?